# Encoding of String like `Ã…land Islands`

Tags: android, character-encoding, android-volley, urlencode

I am trying to post `Ã…land Islands`string using `Volley` but when server receives the string, it converts string to `?land Islands`. Can anyone please let me know

> How to encode such strings  `Ã…land Islands`?

**UPDATE**

```
HashMap params = new HashMap();
        params.put(Constants.FULL_NAME, this.etFullname.getText().toString());
        params.put(Constants.FATHER_NAME, this.etFathername.getText().toString());
        params.put(Constants.CNIC, this.etNic.getText().toString());
        params.put(Constants.PASSPORT, this.etPassport.getText().toString());
        String name = "Ã…land Islands";
params.put(Constants.COUNTRY, name);
```

and Then used the `StringReqeust`

Comment: Can you show the code how you did the post?

Comment: please see the updated code. Used the string param and then post the request using Volley String

Comment: ` when server receives the string` - how you know that it's the server not your code that receives this string?

Comment: Use [`URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to encode the `name`.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: What I am sending, I echo the request from PHP. PHP echo is returning string `?land Island` instead of `Ã…land Islands`. It looks like encoding stuff but don;t know which encoding to use

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Firstly, I am using `Hashmap` to build params which will be sent to `Volley`. Secondly, I wrote this line and got ` Method threw 'java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException' exception.`

Comment: `params.put(Constants.COUNTRY, URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-16LE"));`, or whatever the correct encoding is.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I have tried this but it is creating extra + signs

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Server should also be changed for accepting such string?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Your solution helped me. You can post answer, i'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to encode your parameters<sup>**1**</sup>. Something like,

```
String encoding = "UTF-16LE";
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(Constants.FULL_NAME, URLEncoder.encode(
        this.etFullname.getText().toString(), encoding));
params.put(Constants.FATHER_NAME, URLEncoder.encode(
        this.etFathername.getText().toString(), encoding));
params.put(Constants.CNIC, 
        URLEncoder.encode(this.etNic.getText().toString(), encoding));
params.put(Constants.PASSPORT, URLEncoder.encode(
        this.etPassport.getText().toString(), encoding));
String name = "Ã…land Islands";
params.put(Constants.COUNTRY, URLEncoder.encode(name, encoding));
```

<sup>**1**<sub>Also, you should program to the `Map` interface and *please* don't use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).</sub></sup>